# Argument must be String in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django

Watch this my filteration And please give me solution of this and why this showing this type of error?

```
def create(self,request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        data = serializer.data

        sub = data['subject_id']
        sub_id = Subject.objects.filter(id=sub)

        sec = data['section_id']
        sec_id = Section.objects.filter(id=sec)

        teacher  = data['teacher_id']
        teacher_id = Teacher.objects.filter(id=teacher)

        if sub_id and sec_id and teacher_id:
            TeacherSection.objects.get_or_create(section_id = sec_id.first(),
                                                defaults={
                                                'subject_id':sub_id.first(),
                                                'teacher_id':teacher_id.first()
                                                })
            return Response(data)
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'Detail':['Either Section Or Teacher Or Subject Not Exist']
                })
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({
            'Detail':[serializer.errors]
            })
```

error is like This. And  cound u explain what type of error is this

return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Subject'

Comment: you passing the model itself, instead you should pass the `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subject_id` expects integer-like object. But you are passing the **`sub_id.first()`** which is a **`Subject`** instance.
So it should be

```
sub_id.first().id
```

I think this scenario is also applicable for `teacher_id`. (which depends on how you have defined the models)

Comment: How t do it i donr know im new in stackOverFlow

Comment: @DineshKc To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)